# HttpClient token refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, access-token, angular2-services

I have this interceptor:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

import {SessionStorageService} from 'ng2-webstorage';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private sessionStorage: SessionStorageService) {
    }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const url = '/';
        req = req.clone({
            url: url + req.url,
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', this.sessionStorage.retrieve('access_token'))
        });
        return next.handle(req).catch(err => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                console.log('interceptor error');
                console.log(err);
                if (err.status === 401) {

                    return Observable.throw(err);
                }


            }
        });

    }
}
```

What I need is to get a new token (end request to some 'url' with params) when current is expired and if I get response 401 on any request, then hold the request (and all other requests) until I get a new token. And if *refresh_token* is also expired (also got 401) then do something else.

```
params: new HttpParams().set('Token',  this.sessionStorage.retrieve('refresh_token'))
```

I can't understand how to do request for new token.

What I did next

```
if (err.status === 401) {
                    const params = new HttpParams().set('token', this.sessionStorage.retrieve('refresh_token'));
                    req = req.clone({
                        method:'post',
                        url: url + '/auth/refresh',
                        params: params,
                        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', this.sessionStorage.retrieve('refresh_token'))
                    });
                     next.handle(req).subscribe(res => {

                        console.log('res',res);
                    });
                    return Observable.throw(err);
                }
```

But I got `res` with `body` and other unnecessary for my data. How can I get only `data` from `body`?

When I am trying to do something like `res.body` or `res._body` or `res.text()` I got an error like:

```
Property '_body' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<any>'.
Property '_body' does not exist on type 'HttpSentEvent'.
```

`res['body']` helps me. But I get a string data. When I tried to do `JSON.parse(res['body']);` My request status is go to `cancel`. And I can't do the request.

Comment: You can try : `res.json()`

Comment: if you're getting `401` that means you have to deal with `HttpErrorResponse` type. That one has property `error`˙which is what you need: it will contain whatever server returned in error response body. ref: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse (look at description section)

Answer (score 0):

The response from `next.handle(req)` has the type `HttpEvent`, if you're interested in the actual response event you have to do:

```
if (res instanceof HttpResponse) {
  const body = res.body;
  // to something with the response body
}
```

More can be found at the [**docs**](https://next.angular.io/guide/http#events).